# What is a good way of dealing with NaN in JSON

Tags: json, swift

I am consuming JSON strings in the form of (example):

```
{ "mean" : 0.000000, "std" : -1.0, "skew" : nan, "amount" : 0.000000 }
```

Some of the value may be nan - the device that produces these is not under my control. JSONSerialization.jsonObject() crashes on this as 'nan' is not a valid value it is set to decode (see here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization)

I can 'fix' this by doing things like this:

```
correctedJsonStr = jsonStr.replacingOccurances(of:"nan", with: "0")
```

or

```
correctedJsonStr = jsonStr.replacingOccurances(of:"nan", with: "<null>")
```

But I think this is quit hacky - if any of the keys/values in the JSON string contains e.g. 'bananas' it will be converted also.

Do I really have to create a wrapper class and dig through all the values in search of 'nan' or is there a better, simpler, more intuitive way?

Comment: If `nan` isn't valid JSON then you should report the bug to the developers of the device generating the bad JSON.

Comment: sure, and they may change the firmware years/months from now or never. I need to consume the data no matter what and want to have a defensive coding strategy which is able to deal with a nan.

Comment: You would  have to skip all strings in a textual replacement (which is not entirely trivial because quotation marks can be escaped inside a string). – Perhaps try to find a 3rd party open source JSON parser which you can modify.

Answer (score 1):

Per https://json.org `nan` is not a valid json value.

`JSONSerialization` has no options for dealing with `NaN` so you are stuck doing string replace if you need to deal with that value using those apis.

`JSONDecoder` does have an option for dealing with `NaN` but it will still need to be valid JSON so `NaN` would need to be represented by a string. Here is an example:

```swift
var json = """
{"test": "NaN"}
"""

struct Test: Codable {
  var test: Float
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy = .convertFromString(
  positiveInfinity: "Infinity",
  negativeInfinity: "-Infinity",
  nan: "NaN"
)
let decoded = try! decoder.decode(Test.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(decoded) // prints: Test(test: nan)
```

I couldn't find any third party JSON libraries that handle `NaN`.

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks. It's been a while since I first brought up the issue and I did (sort of) resolve it at the time. Nice you gave it some more thought. API creators better return a result value along with result status but that is often not done. So this NaN thing still needs man handling from time to time.